# Update if the value already exists vb to access database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I'm still learning a lot about visual basic. Now I found out that, unlike in mySQL, access doesn't accept `INSERT ... VALUES .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..`

Now, I was wondering how could that be done otherwise? Below is a part of my (uncleaned/dirty) code. It should check for a duplicate "RentalID", if the id is found, only the the date and amount values that are part of the ID should be changed, in the accdb.

Not sure if it is possible this way, if there's an easier way I'm happy to learn about it!

My code is as follows:

````
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='databasefile.accdb'"
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim rentalid = Me.TextBox1.Text
        Dim amount = Me.TextBox3.Text
        Dim date = Me.TextBox4.Text

        Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO betaling(rentalID, date, amount) values (@rentalid, @date, @amount);"



        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQL, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Try
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO betaling(rentalID, amount, Date) values (@id, @bedrag, @datum);"

                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@rentalid", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.TextBox1.Text))
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@amount", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.TextBox3.Text))
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@date", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.TextBox4.Text))


                cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
                cmd.Parameters("@bedrag").Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
                cmd.Parameters("@datum").Value = Me.TextBox4.Text


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("saved!")

                Me.Close()
                Exit Sub
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

        End Try
        Me.Close()
    End Sub```
````

Comment: Check first if row exists then update or insert accordingly

Comment: @nacho yes, I found that thread, but I don't know how I should implement that in my code..

Comment: Using your current code you could include an update procedure in your exception handle if the exception is of a certain type. Otherwise you will have to check if the PK(s) exist prior to either INSERT or UPDATE

Comment: I don't know much about vb.net, but in your code, when you a get a Exception because PK allready exists, you need to make an update as @Mr.Tripodi says

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that, but It just doesn't want to update for some reason..